# How can I feed ForEach with items of TupleView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a custom view which adds space between each content of TupleView, here is my pseudocode until now! What I should do more in codes to make it happen?

```
struct CustomSpacerView<Content1: View, Content2: View, Content3: View>: View {
    
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> TupleView<(Content1, Content2, Content3)>
    
    var body: some View {

        ForEach(Array(arrayLiteral: content().value).indices, id:\.self) { index in
            
            Spacer()
            
            content().value.index
            
        }
        
        Spacer()
 
    }
    
}
```

use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        CustomSpacerView {

            Text("Hello, World!")
            
            Text("Hello, World!")
            
            Text("Hello, World!")
            
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You may find my [ViewExtractor](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor) package useful for this

Comment: @George: You did the same thing that I wanted to do! Instead of Spacer with Divider! Cheers! Have you used any dependency or it is all Swift and SwiftUI?

Comment: The package is written in pure Swift & SwiftUI, have a look through the code to see how it works! Currently, it's only one source file

Comment: Nice, I see a `getViews` is it open source or closed? I believe I need to learn about it to answer my question. Oh I see the codes now! thanks

Comment: The `getViews` method is public, and will give you an array of `AnyView`. However, look at the example in the README - create your init like that (you'll need both, but can always pass in more parameters).

Comment: Your `ViewExtractor` is pretty good and you covered all scenarios!

Comment: Good to know, I'll add it as an answer with an example

Comment: @George: So I was right about think to use Mirror for extracting TupleView! before you gave me your project link, I mentioned to Asperi about it, and I could extract my tupleView to array of Any but that was it, I should converted it to AnyView or View, and I see you did the same thing with good explaining.

Comment: Yeah, with some playing around with bytes and creating a 'fake' SwiftUI `View` type. Added a summary to the bottom of my answer

Comment: @George: There is No doubts your codes works but some developer are fricking up of using `Mirror` in codes or projects. Is there any issue or potential issue with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239588/discussion-between-george-and-swiftpunk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [ViewExtractor](https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor) package. Here is an example with your code:

```
struct CustomSpacerView: View {
    private let views: [AnyView]

    // For 2 or more views
    init<Views>(@ViewBuilder content: TupleContent<Views>) {
        views = ViewExtractor.getViews(from: content)
    }

    // For 0 or 1 view
    init<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: NormalContent<Content>) {
        views = ViewExtractor.getViews(from: content)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(views.indices) { index in
                Spacer()

                views[index]
            }

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

This has the same usage in `ContentView`.

As an overview, this works by getting a `Mirror` of the content, converting the raw bytes to a 'fake' type representing a `View`, then convert this `Any` type to `AnyView`.